# How to increase my program speed

Tags: java, optimization

i stored data in two different google spreadsheet.one spreadsheet have nearly 1000 entries.I used another spreadsheet to give input .My constraints is compare these two spreadsheet and if common data appear in two spreadsheet than put that data into another spreadsheet.So that i used for loop to compare these two.

My problem is  that it take more time.Is there any other solution to increase my program speed.

Comment: There is no way to tell why your program run slow from the information that you've given.  Some helpful information:

*  What is the size of the data you're working with.  If we're talking about ~10M you could move all your processing to memory.  

*  For loop?  Surely you have at least two.  Give us an idea of your overall algorithm.

*  Most importantly - what is your goal?  How much time does your software currently take and by how much do you need to speed it up.  Some smaller increases can be done quickly, while large increases in speed might require en entire redesign.

Comment: I'm not sure about your implementation (more details would be nice), but can you profile the code to see where the bottleneck is?

Answer (score 5):

If you can, at all, put the data into a database it would really help your read/write speed. Perhaps you can speed it up as is by reading in all the data from both spreadsheets at once and store them in memory then do your comparison?

Without more details on your implementation that is about all I can help you with.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your speed problem comes from incorrect algorithm. If you loop, as you said over two documents, you have something like this:

```
for i in doc1:
  for j in doc2:
    if (compare(i,j) == 0) output(i)
```

This is 1000000 operations for 1000 items documents, which is slow.

There's an easy improvement for that and it's based on sorting items. So you can append those 2 documents, sort them and iterate over array. This will make around 4000 operations, which is huge improvement.

It doesn't matter whether it's Java or Visual Basic.

I believe, you can also do this kind of operation fast in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

- Create two `HashSet` instances and put each document's entries into one of them.
- Create the intersection of the two sets using [`set1.retainAll(set2)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))
- `set1` now contains only those entries that are present in both documents
- Runs about 100 times faster than using nested loops

Answer (score 0):

If your spreadsheets are Excel ones, don't use Java for this, code it in VBA as an Excel macro, it will be 100 times easier... and probably also 100 times faster.

Comment: but i used google spreadsheet